# requesting password while git push in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter, kaggle

I am trying to push the commited changes from kaggle kernels using jupyter notebook but while pushing the changes git asking me for username and I really don't know how to give username as it seems there is no textbox or anything where I can type my username.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following command:

`git push https://username:password@myrepository.biz/file.git --all`

`git push https://username:password@myrepository.biz/file.git master`

Found in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29776651/10929995

Comment: To hide username/password you can use the menu option "Add-ons"->"Secrets"->"Add a new secret".